# How to add record to rth column of nth row table jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table having 6 columns of which 5 are poplated and the  last column for all rows is empty.

Now I need to add some data in the last column of each row , how do I loop over the table using for loop and do the same?

Comment: Step 1: Google it. Step 2: Open your favorite code editor and start typing. Step 3 (optional): if you run into problems, come back here __with your code__

Comment: At least post you table's HTML and the code you tried. Code requests generally are badly received on SO. You have to demonstrated that you tried something to get help on it. Mention what is not working as expected and the errors your getting. Read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints on asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rows` collection of the table with a `for of` statement, then use the `.cells` collection on each row to get the last one.

```js
for (const row of document.querySelector("#myTable").rows) {
  row.cells[row.cells.length-1].textContent = "some dynamic data";
}
```

```css
table td:last-child {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table id=myTable>
<tbody>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

Or use `querySelectorAll` to select the last cell of each row directly.

```js
for (const cell of document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td:last-child")) {
  cell.textContent = "some dynamic data";
}
```

```css
table td:last-child {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<table id=myTable>
<tbody>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
<tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

You could even add `:empty` to the selection to only select empty cells. `document.querySelectorAll("#myTable td:last-child:empty")`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with one more `jQuery` solution https://jsfiddle.net/5htkr87L/

```js
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function(){
 $(this).find('td').last().html("Last");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
    <tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
    <tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
    <tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
    <tr><td>first</td><td>second</td><td>third</td><td>fourth</td><td></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've used `jQuery` `.each` method to loop through all the tr & looking of last td using `jQuery` `last` method.

Hope this will help you.